# Why SWIG requires helper functions to deal with array?

Tags: perl, swig

Quoted from [here](http://www.swig.org/papers/Perl98/swigperl.htm):

> Ideally, a user might want to pass
>   Perl arrays as arguments as follows:

```
@a = (10,20,30,40);
@b = (50,70,60,200);
gd::plotpts($im,\@a,\@b,4,1); # Error!
```

> However, this script generates a type
>   error instead of acting as one might
>   expect. While such behavior may seem
>   restrictive or bizarre, SWIG has been
>   deliberately designed to operate in
>   this manner. In fact, there are even
>   benefits to this approach. If Perl
>   arrays were to be used as C arrays, a
>   copy would be made, verified for
>   type-correctness, and deallocated
>   every time an array was passed to a C
>   function. For large arrays, this would
>   introduce a substantial performance
>   overhead. Space requirements are also
>   a concern for some C programs. For
>   example, a numerical application might
>   manipulate arrays with millions of
>   elements. Converting such arrays to
>   and from a Perl representation would
>   clearly introduce substantial memory
>   and performance overhead. In contrast,
>   manipulating pointers to such arrays
>   is easy and efficient.

But I don't quite understand why it's wrong,can someone illustrate in more detail!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C arrays are very different from Perl arrays.  A Perl array is really a C structure combined with some `malloc`ed memory.  You cannot just simple use a Perl array as a C array.  So something needs to convert the Perl array into a C array and possible back again.  This is not necessarily straight forward.  Therefore swig forces you to write the code to do it.  That is what the helper functions do.

Comment: I think the answer doesn't hit the nail on the head.It's too general for my specific question.

Comment: I am sorry, but that is it.  You can't use a Perl 5 array as C array, therefore you must convert it.  The conversion is non-trivial, therefore you are required to do it with helper functions.  You might want to clarify what you don't understand about it.

Comment: you mentioned `A Perl array is really a C structure combined with some malloced memory`,is there any reference to check out?

Comment: The best thing I have seen is [PerlGuts Illustrated](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.35/index.html), but there is also [`perldoc perlguts`](http://perldoc.perl.org).